# Javascript/JQuery to make Multidimentional Arrary of all DOM Elements i defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom, multidimensional-array

Lets say i have following `DOM`s on my form:

```
<body>
    <input id="input_1" class="post" type="text" value="abc" />
    <input id="input_2" class="xxxx" type="text" value="xyz" /> <!--TO IGNORE-->
    <input id="input_3" class="post" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    <input id="input_4" class="post" type="radio" checked="checked" />
    <select id="input_5" class="post">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
    </select>
    <input id="input_6" class="xxxx" type="checkbox" /> <!--TO IGNORE-->
</body>
```

How can i get an value array of all `class="post"` elements?
So an `Multidimentional Array` will be in the way something like:

```
POST_ELEMENTS[0]["input_1"] = "abc";
POST_ELEMENTS[1]["input_3"] = 1;
POST_ELEMENTS[2]["input_4"] = 1;
POST_ELEMENTS[3]["input_5"] = "two";
```

- How to construct this kind of `Array` which is of all specific class `class="post"` please?

Comment: what is the meaning of the 1st dimension?  It seems you only really need a 1D array here.

Comment: may be yes, sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a 2 dimension array, the index of an array will indicate `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

### Array-like jQuery object

You can get an array-like object which allows you to access matching elements already.

```
var posts = $('.post');

alert(posts[0].id); // input_1
alert(posts[0].value); // abc
```

### Array-like pure JS lookup

You can also use the pure JavaScript method `getElementsByClassName` to grab all the elements (though jQuery functions won't work without casting `$()`)

```
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('post');

alert(posts[0].id); // input_1
alert(posts[0].value); // abc
```

### Array

Alernatively to construct an actual array (not an array-like object) you can do this:

```
var posts = [];
$('.post').each(function () {
    posts.push(this);
});

alert(posts[0].id); // input_1
alert(posts[0].value); // abc
```

Comment: `$('.post')` already returns you an array-like, why bother yourself puttting it into another array ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var posts = {}

$('.post').each(function(v,i){
    posts[this.id] = this.value
})
```

Will return you single dimensional array { 'input_1': 1, 'input_2' : 2 }

```
var posts = []

$('.post').each(function(v,i){
    var obj = {}
    obj[this.id] = this.value
    posts.push( obj)
})
```

Will create multidimensional array

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all the nodes with `getElementsByClassName()` and then map those into the format you want:

```
var POST_ELEMENTS = {};
[].forEach.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('post'), 
    function(item) {
        POST_ELEMENTS[item.id] = item.value;
    }
);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oyosoh/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj=[];
  console.log(obj);
$('.post').each(function(key,value)
                {  obj[key]={};
                obj[key][$(value).attr('id')]=$(value).attr('value');               

              });
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhu5013/ancmX/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for there being 2 dimensions - you only need one here as far as I can see:

```
var posts = {};
$('.port').each(function() {
    posts[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

with the result being an object of key/value pairs:

```
posts = {
    'input_1': abc',
    ...
}
```